# Understanding the output of Doc2Vec from Gensim package

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I have some sample sentences that I want to run through a Doc2Vec model. My end goal is a matrix of size (num_sentences, num_features).

I'm using the Gensim package.

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import TaggedDocument
from gensim.models import Doc2Vec
# warning: long sample of data. It's just 40 sentences really though.
labeled_sents = [TaggedDocument(words=['u0644', 'u0646', 'u062f', 'u0646', 'u060c', 'u0628', 'u0631', 'u0637', 'u0627', 'u0646', 'u06cc', 'u06c1', 'u06a9', 'u0627'], tags='400'), TaggedDocument(words=['do', 'pan', 'en', '1713', 'o', 'soar', 'onde', 'se', 'sit', 'xfaa'], tags='401'), TaggedDocument(words=['u0420', 'u044c', 'u043e', 'u043d', 'u0442', 'u0433', 'u0435', 'u043d', '1901', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u041b', 'u043e', 'u0440', 'u0435', 'u043d', 'u0446', 'xa0', 'u0417', 'u0435', 'u0435', 'u043c', 'u0430', 'u043d', '1902', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u0411', 'u0435', 'u043a', 'u0435', 'u0440', 'u0435', 'u043b', 'xa0', 'u041f', 'u0438', 'u0435', 'u0440', 'u041a', 'u044e', 'u0440', 'u0438', 'xa0', 'u041c', 'u0430', 'u0440', 'u0438', 'u044f', 'u041a', 'u044e', 'u0440', 'u0438', '1903', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u0420', 'u0435', 'u043b', 'u0435', 'u0439', '1904', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u041b', 'u0435', 'u043d', 'u0430', 'u0440', 'u0434', '1905', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u0414', 'u0436', 'u0414', 'u0436', 'u0422', 'u043e', 'u043c', 'u0441', 'u044a', 'u043d', '1906', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u041c', 'u0430', 'u0439', 'u043a', 'u0435', 'u043b', 'u0441', 'u044a', 'u043d', '1907', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u041b', 'u0438', 'u043f', 'u043c', 'u0430', 'u043d', '1908', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u041c', 'u0430', 'u0440', 'u043a', 'u043e', 'u043d', 'u0438', 'xa0', 'u0411', 'u0440', 'u0430', 'u0443', 'u043d', '1909', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u0412', 'u0430', 'u043d', 'xa0', 'u0434', 'u0435', 'u0440', 'xa0', 'u0412', 'u0430', 'u0430', 'u043b', 'u0441', '1910', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u0412', 'u0438', 'u043d', '1911', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u0414', 'u0430', 'u043b', 'u0435', 'u043d', '1912', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u041a', 'u0430', 'u043c', 'u0435', 'u0440', 'u043b', 'u0438', 'u043d', 'u0433', 'xa0', 'u041e', 'u043d', 'u0435', 'u0441', '1913', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u0424', 'u043e', 'u043d', 'xa0', 'u041b', 'u0430', 'u0443', 'u0435', '1914', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u0423', 'u0438', 'u043b', 'u044f', 'u043c', 'u041b', 'u0411', 'u0440', 'u0430', 'u0433', 'xa0', 'u0423', 'u0438', 'u043b', 'u044f', 'u043c', 'u0425', 'u0411', 'u0440', 'u0430', 'u0433', '1915', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u0411', 'u0430', 'u0440', 'u043a', 'u043b', 'u0430', '1917', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u041f', 'u043b', 'u0430', 'u043d', 'u043a', '1918', 'xa0', 'u2022', 'u0429', 'u0430', 'u0440', 'u043a', '1919'], tags='402'), TaggedDocument(words=['nagusia', 'da'], tags='403'), TaggedDocument(words=['sino', 'que', 'los', 'ciudadanos', 'pueden', 'elegir', 'detraer', 'un', 'porcentaje', 'de', 'sus', 'impuestos', 'para', 'esta', 'causa', '68', '69', 'un', 'sistema', 'similar', 'se', 'da', 'en', 'alemania', 'o', 'austria', 'aunque', 'all', 'xed', 'se', 'impone', 'un', 'impuesto', 'eclesi', 'xe1stico'], tags='404'), TaggedDocument(words=['1244', 'c', 'xfc'], tags='405'), TaggedDocument(words=['u062a', 'u063a', 'u064a', 'u064a', 'u0631', 'u0644', 'u0641', 'u0638', 'u0627', 'u0644', 'u0643', 'u0644', 'u0645', 'u0629', 'u060c', 'u0641', 'u0645', 'u062b', 'u0644', 'u0627', 'u064b', 'rat', 'u062a', 'u0644', 'u0641', 'u0638', 'u0631', 'u0627', 'u062a'], tags='406'), TaggedDocument(words=['d', 'xfcrziler'], tags='407'), TaggedDocument(words=['xung', 'quanh', 'u0111', 'xf3'], tags='408'), TaggedDocument(words=['oblika', 'u0161to'], tags='409'), TaggedDocument(words=['u0432', 'u0430', 'u043b', 'u044e', 'u0442', 'u043d', 'u043e', 'u0433', 'u043e', 'u0441', 'u043e', 'u044e', 'u0437', 'u0443'], tags='410'), TaggedDocument(words=['sacerdotal', 'es'], tags='411'), TaggedDocument(words=['natoque', 'nisi'], tags='412'), TaggedDocument(words=['u0631', 'u0627', 'u0645', 'u06cc', 'u200c', 'u062a', 'u0648', 'u0627', 'u0646', 'u062f', 'u0631', 'u0627', 'u06cc', 'u0627', 'u0644', 'u0627', 'u062a', 'u0645', 'u062a', 'u062d', 'u062f', 'u0647', 'u0622', 'u0645', 'u0631', 'u06cc', 'u06a9', 'u0627', 'u06a9', 'u0627', 'u0646', 'u0627', 'u062f', 'u0627', 'u0628', 'u0631', 'u0632', 'u06cc', 'u0644', 'u0648', 'u0622', 'u0631', 'u0698', 'u0627', 'u0646', 'u062a', 'u06cc', 'u0646'], tags='413'), TaggedDocument(words=['u0423', 'u0439', 'u0433', 'u0443', 'u0440', 'u0441', 'u044c', 'u043a', 'u0430', 'u043c', 'u043e', 'u0432', 'u0430'], tags='414'), TaggedDocument(words=['termin', 'poznat', 'kao'], tags='415'), TaggedDocument(words=['les', 'fr', 'xe8res', 'lumi', 'xe8re'], tags='416'), TaggedDocument(words=['26', 'u03c0', 'u03b5', 'u03c1', 'u03af', 'u03c0', 'u03bf', 'u03c5', 'u03b1', 'u03b9', 'u03ce', 'u03bd', 'u03b5', 'u03c2', 'u03b7', 'u03c0', 'u03cc', 'u03bb', 'u03b7', 'u03c4', 'u03b7', 'u03c2', 'u0391', 'u03c5', 'u03bb', 'u03ce', 'u03bd', 'u03b1', 'u03c2', 'u03b5', 'u03af', 'u03bd', 'u03b1', 'u03b9', 'u03c3', 'u03ae', 'u03bc', 'u03b5', 'u03c1', 'u03b1'], tags='417'), TaggedDocument(words=['xcen', '13'], tags='418'), TaggedDocument(words=['acts', 'of', 'civil', 'disobedience', 'forced', 'the', 'head', 'of', 'the', 'local'], tags='419'), TaggedDocument(words=['hugo', 'az', 'xe1llamcs', 'xedny'], tags='420'), TaggedDocument(words=['f', 'xf8rste', 'nu', 'uofficielle', 'vers', 'forbindes', 'ofte', 'med', 'nynazistiske', 'synspunkter'], tags='421'), TaggedDocument(words=['gisulti', 'kanila', 'sa', 'mga', 'langyaw', 'nagtuong', 'gipangutana', 'sila', 'kon'], tags='422'), TaggedDocument(words=['u043d', 'u0430', 'u0438', 'u0432', 'u0440', 'u0438', 'u0442'], tags='423'), TaggedDocument(words=['its', 'influence'], tags='424'), TaggedDocument(words=['a', 'b', 'azerbaijan', 'homeowners', 'evicted', 'for', 'city'], tags='425'), TaggedDocument(words=['dinast', 'xeda', 'lunar', 'de'], tags='426'), TaggedDocument(words=['2', 'wyznawa', 'u0142o', 'judaizmu', '5', 'ponad'], tags='427'), TaggedDocument(words=['quyosh', 'vaqt', 'degani'], tags='428'), TaggedDocument(words=['u306e', 'u884c', 'u4fe1', 'u30fb', 'u91cd', 'u5f18', 'u3001', 'u9678', 'u5965', 'u56fd', 'u306e', 'u821e', 'u8349', 'u6d3e', 'u3001', 'u51fa', 'u7fbd', 'u56fd', 'u306e', 'u6708', 'u5c71', 'u6d3e', 'u3001', 'u4f2f', 'u8006', 'u56fd', 'u306e', 'u5b89', 'u92fc', 'u6d3e', 'u3001', 'u5099', 'u4e2d', 'u56fd', 'u306e', 'u53e4', 'u9752', 'u6c5f', 'u6d3e', 'u306e', 'u5b88', 'u6b21', 'u30fb', 'u6052', 'u6b21', 'u30fb', 'u5eb7', 'u6b21', 'u30fb', 'u8c9e', 'u6b21', 'u30fb', 'u52a9', 'u6b21', 'u30fb', 'u5bb6', 'u6b21', 'u30fb', 'u6b63', 'u6052', 'u3001', 'u8c4a', 'u5f8c', 'u56fd', 'u306e', 'u5b9a', 'u79c0', 'u6d3e', 'u3001', 'u85a9', 'u6469', 'u56fd', 'u306e', 'u53e4', 'u6ce2', 'u5e73', 'u6d3e', 'u306e', 'u884c', 'u5b89', 'u306a', 'u3069', 'u304c', 'u5b58', 'u5728', 'u3059', 'u308b', '7', '8', '9'], tags='429'), TaggedDocument(words=['p', 'xe5', '4'], tags='430'), TaggedDocument(words=['editovat'], tags='431'), TaggedDocument(words=['u0437', 'u0437', 'u0430', 'u0431', 'u043e', 'u0439', 'u0441', 'u0442', 'u0432', 'u0430', 'u043c', 'u0443'], tags='432'), TaggedDocument(words=['10', 'u043b', 'u0438', 'u043f', 'u043d', 'u044f', '1943', 'u0440', 'u043e', 'u043a', 'u0443', 'u0441', 'u043e', 'u044e', 'u0437', 'u043d', 'u0438', 'u043a', 'u0438', 'u0432', 'u0438', 'u0441', 'u0430', 'u0434', 'u0438', 'u043b', 'u0438', 'u0441', 'u044f', 'u0432', 'u0421', 'u0438', 'u0446', 'u0438', 'u043b', 'u0456', 'u0457', 'u0406', 'u0442', 'u0430', 'u043b', 'u0456', 'u0439', 'u0441', 'u044c', 'u043a', 'u0456'], tags='433'), TaggedDocument(words=['136', 'selvom', 'det', 'egentligt', 'ligger', 'i', 'sundby', 'p', 'xe5', 'lollandssiden', 'af', 'guldborgsund', 'centret', 'blev', 'grundlagt', 'i', '1989', 'da', 'byen', 'fejrede', '700', 'xe5rs', 'jubil', 'xe6um', 'bymuseet', 'rekonstruerede', 'som', 'de', 'f', 'xf8rste', 'i', 'verden', 'en', 'middelalderlig', 'kastemaskine', 'kaldet', 'en', 'blide'], tags='434'), TaggedDocument(words=['latine', 'redditur'], tags='435'), TaggedDocument(words=['ljubljani', 'in', 'njeni'], tags='436'), TaggedDocument(words=['u0442', 'u0430', 'u043d', 'u044b', 'u043c', 'u0430', 'u043b', 'u049b', 'u043e', 'u043d', 'u0430', 'u049b', 'u04af', 'u0439', 'u043b', 'u0435', 'u0440'], tags='437'), TaggedDocument(words=['u2022', 'hassib', 'ben'], tags='438'), TaggedDocument(words=['kurtulmu', 'u015f', 'olan', 'u0130talya'], tags='439')]

model = Doc2Vec(documents=labeled_sents, size=10, alpha=.035, window=4, 
    sample=1e-5, workers=4, min_count=1)
```

Now, I thought that `model.docvecs` would give me a list of arrays, with the first array corresponding to the vector for sentence 1, the second array corresponding to the vector for sentence 2, etc. But instead, it's got length 10!

I get `model.docvecs[0] = array([ 0.02312995, -0.00339695, -0.01273827,  0.01944644, -0.03247212, -0.04663946,  0.01369059,  0.03289782,  0.03516903, -0.03435936], dtype=float32)`

What are these `docvecs` then? How do I get the output desired, which is a matrix of dimensions (40, 10) in this example?

---

I saw this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321209/doc2vec-how-to-get-document-vectors), and the correct answer says at the bottom "where 99 is the document id whose vector we want." So this makes me even more confused, as he seems to say that `model.docvecs` SHOULD be indexing a matrix where each row is a document vector!

Answer (score 4):

`TaggedDocument` expects tags to be a **`list`** of tags related to document.

In your case,

```
sentence = TaggedDocument(words=['a', 'b'], tags='400')
```

gets interpreted as sentence having 3 tags `['4','0','0']`, and hence `model.docvecs` returns vectors corresponding to 10 tags - `['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']`

Try changing this to

```
sentence = TaggedDocument(words=['a', 'b'], tags=['400'])
```

Answer (score 3):

`model.docvecs` is an iterable with length equal to the number of documents you supplied the model. Each `docvec` is a vector representation of a single *document*. Its length is determined by the `size` parameter that you gave it when you trained the model. `size` is commonly between 100 and 300, and sometimes longer. A vector of length 10 would do a poor job at representing the documents you fed it.

Thus, something like this would be more productive:

```
for i in range(0, len(lot)):
    docs.append(gn.models.doc2vec.TaggedDocument(words=lot[i], tags=[i]))
```

Where `lot` is a list of lists of tokens (words) like this:

```
lot = [['the','cat','sat'],['the','dog','ran']]
```

Running the model:

```
gn.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(docs, size=300, window=8, dm=1, hs=1, alpha=.025, min_alpha=.0001)
```