# Doc2vec: model.docvecs is only of length 10

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, doc2vec

I am trying doc2vec for 600000 rows of sentences and my code is below:

```
model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(size= 100, min_count = 5,window=4, iter = 50, workers=cores)
model.build_vocab(res) 
model.train(res, total_examples=model.corpus_count, epochs=model.iter)

#len(res) = 663406

#length of unique words 15581
print(len(model.wv.vocab))

#length of doc vectors is 10
len(model.docvecs)

# each of length 100
len(model.docvecs[1])
```

How do I interpret this result? why is the length of vector only 10 with each of size 100? when the length of 'res' is 663406, it does not make sense. I know something is wrong here.

In [Understanding the output of Doc2Vec from Gensim package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37196520/understanding-the-output-of-doc2vec-from-gensim-package?rq=1), they mention that the length of docvec is determined by 'size' which is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

The `tags` of a `TaggedDocument` should be a list-of-tags. If you instead provided strings, like `tags='73215'`, that would be seen as if the same as the list-of-characters:

```
tags=['7', '3', '2', '1', '5']
```

At the end, you'd only have 10 tags in your whole training set, just the 10 digits in various combinations.

That your `len(model.docvec[1])` is 100 means you didn't make exactly this error, but perhaps something similar, in constructing your `TaggedDocument` training data.

Look at the first item in `res`, to see if its `tags` property makes sense, and each of the `model.docvecs`, to see what's being used instead of what you intended.